# Long_scalars Error by creating a pivot table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, create-table

i am new in python programmation

On my project, i try to creat a pivot table, by using the id of the songs as index, popularity as value, name as columns , by typing the code below:

```
user_song = pd.pivot_table(dataset, index=['track_id'], values=['popularity'], columns=['track_name'])
```

But, it shows me this error message:

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in long_scalars
  num_cells = num_rows * num_columns
```

When I remove the " columns " argument, no problem happen but the code misses all columns.

```
user_song = pd.pivot_table(dataset, index=['track_id'], values=['popularity'])
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample input and expected output (as text, not picture)?

Comment: I have a song dataset with 114000 rows and 21 columns ( include id, name, rating of the song ), what i want is to create a matrix where each column is a song name and each row contains the rating assigned by a specific user to that song, then i got those problems by creating it with " pivot table "